# How can I find a general form for this sequence? $2, 1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 16, 7, \ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> I am trying to find a general form for this sequence
>
> $$2, 1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 16, 7, \ldots$$

It's obvious that the odd terms are powers of 2 and the even terms are odd numbers but I can't figure a mathematical way to write this.

Thanks.

Comment: Knowing a finite number of terms of a sequence tells us nothing about the subsequent terms.  If we ignore that and assume your interpretation is correct, then you could write a piecewise function for the even and odd terms of the sequence.

Comment: Try Sloan's online encyclopedia of integer sequences. It is a useful tool for the future.

Comment: Sloan's encyclopedia returned no results in this case. Still, it is a useful tool, so I will leave my previous comment here.

Answer (score 6):

**Hints:**

You could use that $\dfrac{1-(-1)^n}2$ is $1$ when $n$ is odd and $0$ otherwise,

and $\dfrac {1+(-1)^n}{2} $ is $0$ when $n$ is odd and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to generalise this to more than 2 cases, for example if we wanted to have 3 possibilities were at any given time 2 will be 0 , e.g. (1,0,0 ), (0,1,0) , (0,0,1) . This formulae covers the case for (1,0),(0,1) alternating.

Comment: Yes, @Arjang; for $3,$ let $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3),$ then $(\omega^{2(n-k)}+\omega^{n-k}+1)/3$ is $1$ when $n\equiv k\pmod 3$ and $0$ when $n\not\equiv k\pmod3$, and this can be generalized

Answer (score 6):

$$a_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}(n-1) +\frac {1+(-1)^{n-1}}{2}(2^{\frac {n+1}{2}})$$

Comment: Since I am still learning, It would be great if you could explain your approach. Thanks.

Comment: For odd indices the formula is a power of $2$ and for even indecese the formula is $n-1$

Comment: The multipliers involving $(-1)^n$ are either $0$ or $(1)$ to fit the combined pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to generalise this to more than 2 cases, for example if we wanted to have 3 possibilities were at any given time 2 will be 0 , e.g. (1,0,0 ), (0,1,0) , (0,0,1) .
This formulae covers the case for (1,0),(0,1) alternating.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the first term has the index $0$, you can simply write

$$\begin{cases}t_{2n}&=2^{n+1},\\t_{2n+1}&=2n+1.\end{cases}$$

---

If you insist to have a one-liner,

$$t_n=\,(1-n\bmod2)\,2^{n/2+1}+(n\bmod2)\,n.$$

---

Or

$$t_n=(\sqrt2)^n+(-\sqrt2)^n+2n\left\{\frac n2\right\}$$ where the curly brackets denote the fractional part.

---

The sequence can also be described by a first-order recurrence

$$\begin{cases}t_0=2,\\
t_{n+1}=(t_n\bmod2)2^{(t_n+1)/2}+(1-t_n\bmod2)(2\log_2t_n-1).\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Arjang: the quiz is fun.

Comment: @Arjang: I disagree with the ubiquitous statement about the number of terms, which allows arbitrary extrapolation: the purpose is implicitly to try to reach the *shortest* expression that generates the given numbers. If the allowed syntax is specified, the minimum exists. For $1,2,4,8,\cdots$, can you do better than $2^n$ ? And can you lengthen the sequence with a shorter formula than $2^n$ if the next term is not allowed to be $16$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n = 2^{\frac {n-1}2}(1-\cos(n\pi))+(n-1)(\frac {\cos( n\pi)+1}2)$$

Thats what I found